# PHP save form data on reload

Tags: php, html

So i got this form:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
Dogecoin-address:  <input type="text" name="address"/><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
// starting the session
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['address'])) { 
$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['Submit'];
} 
?>
```

i want to keep"address"data here: when i reload this:

```
$url = 'https://faucethub.io/api/v1/send? 
api_key=4b21af7e916403216ffb11e523f912bc&currency=DOGE&amount=1&to='. 
$_POST['address'];

$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...

$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
var_dump($result);
?>
```

when the user submit his "address" i want his "address"remain/save on the second code when he refreshes!
how is this possible by using $_SESSION?OR by using cookies?or any other way?
i'm new to php and i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `$_POST` value to address instead of Submit. This way your address is stored inside the `$_SESSION['address']` variable.

You can access the address by using `$_SESSION['address']`.